# Why there is a different translation in 1 Timothy 4:7?

Tags: 1-timothy

> 1 Timothy 4:7 (NIV)
>  Have nothing to do with godless myths and
>   **old wives**' tales; rather, train yourself to be godly.
>
> 1 Timothy 4:7 (ESV)
>  Have nothing to do with irreverent, silly
>   myths. Rather train yourself for godliness

There is "old wives" in NIV but not in ESV.
In my mother language, the translation (if it's in English) is something like this : *"granny's tales"*

Answer (score 3):

“Godless myths and old wives’ tales” and “irreverent, silly myths” mean the same thing within the context of the letter Paul is writing to Timothy.  Just because one translation uses a slightly different phrase is of no significance, theologically speaking.

The ESV Study Bible cross-references this verse to 1 Timothy 1:4 where an instruction is given "not to devote themselves to myths and endless genealogies, which promote speculations rather than the stewardship from God."

> "The Greek word 'mythos' is a negative term characterizing beliefs as fanciful, untrue, and even deceptive. Such myths were often used to excuse immoral behaviour."

Another cross-reference is to Titus 1:14 which refers to "not devoting themselves to Jewish myths."

The NLT Study Bible cross-references Titus 1:14 to Titus 3:9 which says "Do not get involved in foolish discussions about spiritual pedigrees or in quarrels and fights about obedience to Jewish laws."

The NIV Study Bible notes for 1 Timothy 1:4 gives this explanation about myths and endless genealogies:

> “Probably mythical stories built on OT history (genealogies) that later developed into intricate Gnostic philosophical systems.”

In other words, don’t waste time of stuff that doesn’t matter and has nothing to do with your eternal salvation.  Focus on the gospel.  Sound advice, don’t you think?

Edit: The NIV Greek Interlinear uses the Greek words for “old-womanish tales” which is translated into English as “old wives' tales”.  It is only some “politically correct” modern translations that try to avoid the gender issue by changing the wording!  However, the Greek phrase definitely means “old-womanish tales”.

Answer (score 0):

Myths, old wives' tales, mythical stories are all just ways of referring to make believe stories. Different translations use different wordings.

For example, the influence of King James on KJV (authorized by King James in order to have as accurate a translation as possible, which could be printed and widely circulated - [source](http://www.bibleinfo.com/en/questions/history-kjv)) versus a group of people on the New American Bible - Revised Edition (aka NABRE - Released on March 9, is the culmination of nearly 20 years of work by a group of nearly 100 scholars and theologians, including bishops, revisers and editors. [source](http://usccb.org/bible/)).

Overall, I would say that both verses share the meaning of - not worth the time to invest in here on Earth when we should be striving for Sainthood/holiness.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  If you have not already done so, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.